# Alembic: put a "version_num" for each schema

Tags: python, alembic

In my team we have multiple projects/microservices all hosted on the same database, but each service has a specific schema.

I want to manage the migrations of each project independently of other projects, a way of achieving that could be to specify different environments to Alembic, with one environment specific to one schema.

Let's say I have two services : "service1" and "service2", each with a schema that have the name of the project.
I'd like to have the following structure for my code:

```
team
├───service1
│   ├───requirements.txt
│   ├───main.py
│   └───alembic/
└───service2
    ├───requirements.txt
    ├───main.py
    └───alembic/
```

I'd like to be able to

1. navigate to `team/service1`
2. Create a migration and run it

   - have this migration be executed on schema "service1"
3. Go to `team/service2`
4. Create a migration and run it

   - have this migration be executed on schema "service2"

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [`version_table_schema`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.version_table_schema) parameter of the `configure` method in `env.py`:

```
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            version_table_schema="MY_SCHEMA",
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

(Thanks to [CaselIT](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/discussions/940#discussioncomment-1424292))